# /folder/ does not point to .aspx page

Tags: asp.net, iis

A quick question. Pointing to admin panel in my website on IIS 5.1 (XP Pro) like this

```
localhost\testsite\admin\
```

automatically picks default.aspx on my machine but it does not on server2003 which uses IIS 6.0. Do I need to change something for that to work, may be permissions?

Is it a good practice to point to admin/default.aspx or just /admin/. I prefer the later.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your server2003 IIS, have you verified that

1. Default documents are enabled
2. Default.aspx is on the list of Default docs

Right-click your website, Properties->Documents

Comment: they are enabled but default.aspx was not the list. Default.asp was. Thanks

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct if it helped, and consider reviewing answers to your past questions and marking those that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions on this page and ensure that default.aspx is configured as a default document:

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/dc6eb1b4-9028-4308-9935-52b64edfad36.mspx?mfr=true