# vb.net, How do I change a folder name in URL to point at a default aspx page inside the folder?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url-routing

My url is something like this https://mycompanyname.org/myfoldername/default.aspx.

When users type just ../myfoldername/ or ../myfoldername, Can I direct them to ../myfoldername/default.aspx location? Is there a way to do this in vb.net? I saw this question [/folder/ does not point to .aspx page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878804/folder-does-not-point-to-aspx-page) but couldn't achieve what I wanted. Thank you for the help.

Comment: That's a server administration question, you must configure the default document on IIS.

Comment: Add a default.aspx page in each folder and add a response.redirect() in the code behind or a meta tag redirect in whichever page you want redirection

Comment: The server setting is the best place for it, although there is a web.config directive that would do it as well.